# How to use a generic class as a parameter and extend the type?

Tags: java, generics

I am attempting to use generics in my project to have a base class that can make use of different types of objects. But I am having trouble when trying to pass these generic typed classes as parameters in some cases.

So I guess my question is, is there any way to use a certain generic typed interface and pass in extensions of the generic type?

I am sorry if I am phrasing this strangely, I am not very used to trying to explain these types of questions. I would be glad for some kind of insight into generics, I feel like I can't get a grip on how they really worked. I have read many posts about them but I couldn't find any that describe my problem or really help me understand it all.

I have tried numerous variations on extending the generic type T, also trying to use wildcards. But I always just end up with way to many nested generics and captures of wildcards and I just make a mess.

I have this interface:

```
public interface NiceObject<T extends SomeClass> {}
```

And then I want to be able to extend it with different implementations:

```
public class EpicClass extends SomeClass {}
```

```
public class CoolObject implements NiceObject<EpicClass> {}
```

This works fine for me, but when I attempt to pass an implementation of `NiceObject` as a parameter of type `NiceObject<T>` where T is an extension of `SomeClass` it tells me that the type is not applicable.

```
public void coolMethod(NiceObject<SomeClass> obj);
```

```
CoolObject obj = new CoolObject();
coolMethod(obj);
// this does not work
```

I have also tried changing the method in some ways:

```
public void coolMethod(NiceObject<?> obj);

public void coolMethod(NiceObject<? extends SomeClass> obj);

public <S extends SomeClass> void coolMethod(NiceObject<S> obj);

// None of these produce my desired result
// I just end up with non-applicable parameters somewhere in my program.
```

EDIT
I'll try to make my question a bit clearer:

```
NiceObject<EpicClass> obj = new CoolObject();
coolMethod(obj);

// Message:
// The method coolMethod(NiceObject<SomeClass>) in the type NiceMethods
// is not applicable for the arguments (NiceObject<EpicClass>)
```

What confuses me is that `EpicClass` is clearly an extension of `SomeClass`, shouldn't the compiler be able to accept it as a `SomeClass` because it inherits the same properties as one?

EDIT 2
It seems like I have resolved my issue now. I have a tendency to solve my problem right after I make a post about it.

As a comment proposed, it was more about the problems it caused in other parts of the program. I didn't want to mix in other parts of my program because the structure of it and my overuse of generics is kind of dumb and I did not want to make it even more confusing.

When I modified the `coolMethod()` to be able to accept any kind of `NiceObject<SomeClass>` other problems appeared. I had methods in a `NiceObject` that had to use it's own type of `NiceObject` as parameters. I solved it by creating a method that would return itself and subtypes would implement that method.

```
public interface NiceObjectUser <N extends NiceObjectUser<N>> {
     public N getSelf();
}
```

I also did other silly things to make the errors disappear and I had to refactor quite a few other classes. in the end though, it works so whatever.

I do appreciate the answer which explained some things about generics which I have now accepted. I now feel like I have a greater level of understanding of generics.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down each piece of your code. Can you also provide a **complete** block of code that we can just copy/paste and compile ourselves?

Comment: Have you tried casting?      coolMethod((NiceObject<EpicClass>) obj)

Comment: "I just end up with non-applicable parameters somewhere in my program" that may just mean that you need to refactor your code a bit if you started to successfully use "coolMethod" with some other parameters. Perhaps you can include example of what is not longer working and we can suggest solution or the solution to address it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that even though `EpicClass` is a subtype of `SomeClass`, `NiceObject<EpicClass>` is a subtype of `NiceObject<SomeClass>`. To see why, consider:

```
class Box<T> {
  private T value;
  T get() {
    return value;
  }

  void set(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Now think of two classes like `Object` and `String`, where `String` is a subtype of `Object`. Let's say we allowed `Box<String>` to be a subtype of `Box<Object>`. That would mean you can use a `Box<String>` anywhere that was expecting a `Box<Object>`. Now think about code like this:

```
Box<String> stringBox = new Box<String>();
Box<Object> objectBox = stringBox;
objectBox.set(new NonStringObject());
String string = stringBox.get(); // Error! Got a NonStringObject() from a string box!
```

In general, the fact that a box might *consume* a `T` or *produce* a `T` means that subtyping rules don't work the way you might expect. In general the proposed alternatives you posted are the way to go when you run into a problem like this; in order to figure out why they're not working we're going to have to know more about the specifics of what you're trying to do.